# Secure with TLS/SSL

Tags: security, ssl

Is there any way to secure network traffic between any two applications with SSL even both applications don't support SSL mode?

---

### Diagram:

(Host X (Application A) ) --------unsecured connection----- (Host Y (Application B) )

(Host X (App. C (App. A)) ) -----secured connection------- (Host Y (App. C (App. B)) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/).

and if it does not have to be ssl, try a ssh tunnel.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try stunnel. I'm interested in securing JDBC but do not want to end up paying lots of $$$ for built-in SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the application but almost certainly yes.

For instance you could just setup an IPSec tunnel, or use IPv6 or lots of other ways - talk to us more about your application please.

Comment: Thanks, the application is Oracle Database 10gR2. I know Oracle offers Oracle Advanced Security, but I prefer not to pay an additional $11k per processor just for JDBC over SSL. I will research IPSec tunnel, but I'm not sure what you mean by IPv6. Thanks again.